# Mouse "buffering" clicks on disabled buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

my program is a text game that emulates a Console output with a TextBox on a WindowsForm.
One feature I'm trying to implement is by clicking a button it will output to the TextBox with a certain speed, which is achieved with this method atm:

```
public static void Write(String text, Color color, TextBox textArea, UI ui)
    {
        ui.Enabled = false;
        foreach (Control b in ui.Controls)//Disable controls
        {
            if (b.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                b.Enabled= false;
        }
        textArea.ForeColor = color;
        foreach (char c in text) //Write the text
        {
            textArea.AppendText(c.ToString());
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                textArea.AppendText("\n");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(30);
        }
        textArea.AppendText("\n");
        foreach (Control b in ui.Controls)//Enable controls
        {
            if (b.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                b.Enabled= true;
        }
        ui.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The button events are called like so:

```
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Core.Write("this is button 1", Color.Red, txtDialog, this);
    }
    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Core.Write("this is button 2", Color.Green, txtDialog, this);
    }
    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Core.Write("this is button 3", Color.Blue, txtDialog,this);
    }
    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Core.Write("this is button 4", Color.White, txtDialog,this);
    }
```

What I've noticed is that, even with the buttons and the form disabled while it does not complete the writing logic, by clicking multiple times on any given button it will "save" that click and output it right after the writing of the previous is done.

What should I do to eradicate this bug? Many thanks

Comment: Are you doing this writing in the thread that consumes your window messages?

Comment: @EdPlunkett edited with the event methods

Comment: @EdPlunkett What don't you understand? `Core.Write` is the 1st method on the question and it's called when a button is clicked.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm really sorry, I placed a 2 min old code that I was trying.. 
the foreach's that run the controls are `b.Enabled` and not `b.Visible`. Sorry

Comment: @diomonogatari Actually it doesn't matter, I tried it both ways. Here's the thing: Disable the whole form in some other way -- then no click on any ever calls the handler or calls Core.Write(). That's what I tested initially. However, your code does actually behave as described when used as directed. I was wrong, it's reproducible and I haven't figured out yet what it's doing. Hans (below) is right, though: Don't do it this way.

Comment: Getting the mouse clicks buffered is not the only thing that goes wrong.  You can't actually *see* the controls getting disabled, hiding buttons has no visible side-effect.  It is bad code.  Never hang the UI thread.  Simulate slow text with a Timer or Task.Delay() in an async method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as I see, this code should not work as you've expected, but it should work as you've described as bug. The situation is not a bug, this is how Windows works. Windows creates a message queue for each application and forward every event to this message queue and main thread (GUI thread for WinForms) of this application, and messages are processed sequentially.

What your code does is, it disables the container (UI?) and hides the buttons and tries to write some text by suspending for a few milliseconds, and then it enabled everything. All are happening in UI thread where it should be processing messages.

Now, when you click, app receives a click event, and runs your code and it takes some time. While your code is running (remember `Thread.Sleep`), user clicks the place where your button is, windows posts message to your app queue to be processed next. When does this messages get processed? After your code completes, since it is the same thread that processes messages and runs your own code. When your code completes (buttons and UI is available again), and then the next message is processed.

Try using a `BackgroundWorker` which runs in another thread.

```
public static void Write(String text, Color color, TextBox textArea, Form ui)
{
    textArea.ForeColor = color;

    var handler = new Action<string>(textArea.AppendText);

    foreach (char c in text) //Write the text
    {
        textArea.Invoke(handler, c.ToString());
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            textArea.Invoke(handler, "\n");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(30);
    }
    textArea.Invoke(handler, "\n");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = true;

}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Write("this is button 1", Color.Red, textBox1, this);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. A lot of people (myself included when I first started using C#) think that events are fired and run on their own thread.  Actually, while an event handler is running, it blocks UI and message handling.  When you disabled the control at the beginning of the function and enabled it at the end of the function - the only time the control is disabled is during the time when it couldn't possibly handle messages - while the event handler was executing and occupying the UI thread.

Comment: @ChrisBerger I'm sure that this knowledge will be really useful in the next challenges of this development. Thank you :)